# PHP Pagination different page call

Tags: php, html, pagination

i use php code for call page using url like this

```
<a href="?page=home">Home</a>
<a href="?page=news">News</a>
<a href="?page=event">Event</a>
etc...
```

many sample pagination using url

```
href="news.php?page=$pageno"
```

my question is how to make link url pagination if using url like

```
href="?page=news"
```

i have try using this code

```
<a href=?page=news?page=$i>$i</a>
```

but not work, Please help??
i am newbie on php

Comment: You can't have `page` in the URL twice. You need to do something like `href=?page=news&pageno=$i` instead. Note the `&` separating the different fields

Comment: the last `page-$i` will be available via `$_GET['page']` only

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. i have try above script , but still not work. the page not response and stay in first page

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is a bit blurry, but try to figure out the logic using the following rudimental code.

In the page where you place your links, enter this:

```
<a href="news.php?page=1">1</a>
```

In your `news.php`:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['page']) {
  // do stuff with $_GET['page'], which is '1' in this case.
}
?>
```

In this example, `$_GET['page']` will evaluate to the number `1`. This variable can then be used to include the news you want to display, be it through including another php-page, or by calling a set of articles from a database.

Don't forget to put `<?php` and `?>` tags around the code, otherwise things won't work.

Comment: Thank you for reply jethro. i use for call page using this metode href="?page=news" not href="news.php", and i put that page on center div so if i use this <a href="news.php?page=1">1</a> my web design gone

Comment: Then your link should be `?page=news&pageNumber=1`. `$_GET['page']` will give you `news`, and `$_GET['pageNumber']` will give you `1`.